# Блок "Поделиться" от Яндекса - пропали счетчики

Tags: ya-share2

Раньше были счетчики. Они есть на первом изображении Конструктора по ссылке https://yandex.ru/dev/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/

Сейчас счетчиков нет ни в конструкторе, ни у меня на сайте. Официальной новости я не нашла. Помоги, разобраться в чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Сообщение от яндекса**

2 августа 2019 года мы убрали из документации описание счетчиков с целью убрать счетчики совсем по нижеследующим причинам.

Гипотеза была в том, что счетчики в наше время не сильно влияют на конверсию кнопок. Однако, они расходуют ресурсы пользователя и требуют более тщательного слежения за изменениями API социальных сетей. Мы провели эксперимент перед выпиливанием счетчиков, конверсия в кнопки не упала.

Второй момент: работоспособность счетчиков обеспечивалась внешними скриптами социальных сетей, что не является безопасным для пользователя, а также не позволяет проверить, действительно ли пользователь опубликовал запись у себя в социальной сети. Поэтому сохранялась вероятность того, что статистика немного лукавит.

Таким образом, в 2020 году счетчики кнопок поделения в социальных сетях являются атавизмом, который не приносит пользы ни пользователю, ни сайту. 30 мая 2020 года мы убрали код для счетчиков из кода Блока "Поделиться".

Тем не менее, информация о количестве поделений вашим сайтов в социальных сетях по-прежнему доступна в Яндекс.Метрике (https://yandex.ru/support/metrica/content/share-button.html?lang=ru).

На каких-то ресурсах могли остаться счетчики, но мы со своей стороны не можем это контролировать. В этих случаях разработчики сайта или конструктора, на котором сделан сайт, используют собственный форк нашего кода, за работоспособность и функциональность которого мы не несем ответственности.

Источник: https://yandex.ru/blog/share/ne-rabotayut-schetchiki

Comment: Извините, а ссылку на источник вы не могли бы добавить. Или вы сотрудник яндекс?

Comment: Ссылку пожлуйста поместите в __ответ__, не комментарием.

Answer (score 1):

Об этой проблеме сообщили десятки людей. Предположительное время возникновения проблемы - май 2020 года. Скорее всего, после введения `Share API 2.0` Яндекс решил принудительно внедрить этот API всем пользователям, заменив старые скрипты на новые, что и привело к исчезновению счётчиков.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Хотелось бы еще найти информацию от представителей Яндекса.